# Problem with mobile view & tablet view responsive media queries

Tags: android, html, jquery, css

I created my website on Dreamweaver and I put it on line. The website address is https://www.economiseur-d-eau.fr.

On Dreamweaver and on line (from my PC through the developer tools), my website is responsive.

Here some screenshots:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIoZU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4X2u.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqC1d.png)

But, from my mobile on line, the mobile view and tablet view are not responsive and don't display correctly.

My HTML ans CSS codes seem to be correct.

Here my website's [code source](https://view-source:https://www.economiseur-d-eau.fr/).

And below my website's CSS code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/*Global / Desktop View*/
header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.70);
  padding-left: auto;
  padding-right: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.mobile-view {
  display: none;
}
.desktop-view ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.desktop-view {
  margin-top: -5px;
}
body {
  font-family: josefin-slab;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: #EAEAEA;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.desktop-view ul li a {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.hero-image {
  height: 450px;
  background-image: url(images/economiseur-d-eau-hero-arriere-plan.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center 0%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
main {
  min-height: 800px;
}
footer {
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.social-icons {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.copyright {
  float: right;
  color: #000000;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.facebook-icon {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.twitter-icon {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.email-icon {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.hero-content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
.guide-achat {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 32px;
}
p {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000000;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
h1 {
  color: #000000;
  font-family: josefin-slab;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
}
hr {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.btn-black {
  background-color: #000000;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
.image-grid {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.col {
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.col-lg {
  width: 31.3%;
}
.responsive-image {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
.image-grid:after {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  content: "";
}
.text-white-description {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.text-red {
  color: #FF0004;
}
.logo {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
/*Tablet View*/
@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .mobile-view {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .desktop-view {
    display: none;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  .expand {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-view ul li {
    display: block;
    background-color: #000000;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
  .hero-content {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
  .col-md {
    width: 48%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
  }
}
/*Mobile View*/
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .mobile-view {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 7px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .desktop-view {
    display: none;
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  .expand {
    display: block;
  }
  .desktop-view ul li {
    display: block;
    background-color: #000000;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  .hero-image {
    height: 400px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
  .hero-content {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .hero-content hr {
    display: none;
  }
  .hero-content p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .col-xs {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
    margin-left: 1%;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 65%;
    height: 65%;
  }
}
```

Could you please have a look on my website and help me fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at the code of your website. Seems like the issue is `viewport` meta tag is missing. Please add the below line in the `<head>` section of your `html` (every page)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Hello, I would like to say to you that I've put the line of code you've provided to me above in the <head> section of my html and it works very well! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Awesome. You can accept the answer then :)